# How implement scheduling event with post a message on fb

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

I am creating an application in which I have add a facility for post message on ur account. Now this facility I am adding an event for scheduling. With help of that user can write a message and post that later or on particular date and time. For this I used a local notification event which is generate on given date by user. But problem is that when notification generate then I have call a function which is used for post message on Facebook. For generate notification I have used this code:

```
-(IBAction)save{
    NSString *str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txt_date.text];
    NSString *str2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",txt_time.text];
    str1=[str1 stringByAppendingFormat:str2];
    selected_label.text= str1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    NSDate *today=[NSDate date]; 
    NSDateFormatter* formatter_current = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    formatter_current.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    //Set the required date format 
    [formatter_current setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"]; 

    NSLog(@"current date is =%@",str1); 
    today=[formatter_current dateFromString:str1];
    NSLog(@"current date:-%@",today); 
    UILocalNotification* ln = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    ln.alertBody = @"Wake Up Sid";
    ln.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    ln.fireDate = today; //[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:15];
    ln.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    NSLog(@"alarm will activate on%@",today);
    NSDateFormatter* formatter_alarm = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSLocale *uslocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [formatter_alarm setLocale:uslocale];
    [uslocale release]; 
    formatter_alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [formatter_alarm setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"]; 
    NSString *str=[formatter_alarm stringFromDate:today];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    ln.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your first appointment at %@",str];
    ln.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    ln.repeatInterval=NSDayCalendarUnit;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:ln];
    [ln release];
}
```

and in appdelegate file I use this function for received notification and call post message function:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.viewController=[[demo_social_updatesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"demo_social_updatesViewController" bundle:nil];
    nav_controller=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:nav_controller.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    appDelegate_acess_token=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"access_token"];
      application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    // Handle launching from a notification
    UILocalNotification *localNotif =
    [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {
        NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",localNotif);
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
    if (application.applicationIconBadgeNumber == 1) {
        BOOL tmp=[Global_Class_parsing post_comment_fb:appDelegate_acess_token uesr_comment:@"testing message111"];
        if(tmp){

            UIAlertView *av = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sucessfully posted to photos & wall!" 
                                                          message:@"Check out your Facebook to see!"
                                                         delegate:nil 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
            [av show];

        }
        else{
            UIAlertView *av = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error"message:@"Check connection!"
                                                         delegate:nil 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
            [av show];
        }
    }

    /*
     Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
     If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
     */
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{
    /*
     Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
    if (application.applicationIconBadgeNumber == 1) {
        BOOL tmp=[Global_Class_parsing post_comment_fb:appDelegate_acess_token uesr_comment:@"testing message111"];
        if(tmp){

            UIAlertView *av = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sucessfully posted to photos & wall!" 
                                                          message:@"Check out your Facebook to see!"
                                                         delegate:nil 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
            [av show];

        }
        else{
            UIAlertView *av = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error"message:@"Check connection!"
                                                         delegate:nil 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
            [av show];
        }
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notification);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Recieved Notification method call.");
    }
}
```

Now problem is that when notification generate and applicationbadge number become 1 then it not call any function and my post message function not calling. So how I fix that error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why didrecivedlocalnotification method not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410638/why-didrecivedlocalnotification-method-not-working). You should just edit the original question if you want to restate it, rather than ask again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get solution for this question is that i have two way to implement scheduling with post method one is simply use notification. And another is use web-service. I have used both and working well.